# How to read a range of time in Librosa?

Tags: python, audio, librosa, rms

I am wondering if there's a way to read a range between specific timing. Currently, I am using librosa to calculate each note of the rms. Here is the following code.

```py
import librosa
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
y, sr = librosa.load(librosa.ex('trumpet'))
librosa.feature.rms(y=y)
S, phase = librosa.magphase(librosa.stft(y))
rms = librosa.feature.rms(S=S)
times = librosa.times_like(rms)
plt.semilogy(times, rms[0], label='RMS Energy')
```

Then, it shows [image]

But Let's say we just want the timing between 1.8 to 2.4. Then, how to do so?

Comment: Did I answer your question? Please take time to review answers from other posts too and either accept them or explain how they are not matching what you were aiming for

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Librosa loads samples to, looking at your code, to `y`. The sampling rate, `sr`, tells you how many samples you have in each second. Knowing the two:

```
time_start_seconds = 1.8 
time_end_seconds = 2.4

time_start_samples = int(time_start_seconds * sr)
time_end_samples = int(time_end_seconds * sr)

new_y = y[time_start_samples: time_end_samples]
```

From there you can proceed with rest of your analysis.

Comment: Yes! Thanks for answering. By the way, could you change ```time_start``` to ```time_start_seconds```? Also the ```time_end one```. Then, I will mark it as the right answer